# Python adding utility functions to SqlAlchemy Entity classes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my Python package, I have defined a number Sqlalchemy Entity classes. All classes are defined using ORM declarative techniques. Most classes map directly to database tables (in a 1:1 fashion) using normal attributes and relationships, with only a couple of classes utilizing simple hybrid_attributes.

When you look at a few other packages like Elixir or Camelot, they have supplemental sqlalchemy features that provide convenience operations as extra attributes attached to each Entity instance. For example, `to_dict()`, which copies an Entity instance to a dictionary and `from_dict()`, which attempts to create a new Entity instance from a dictionary.

What is the **simplest** way to go about manually adding functions like those to my own Entity classes? Looking for generic approaches that will have the fewest caveats for the most common uses.

---

Use metadata/mapper to find the appropriate set of Column keys? (for to_dict)

Class methods? Static methods?

Subclass declarative_base from `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative`?

What about mixins?

Answer (score 0):

I was digging in the source for Elixir and I found how they implemented these helpers...

The functions are defined as regular instance methods on a Parent Base class that is meant to be subclassed, although the elixir `Entity` uses metaclass.

From that implementation, I think I can subclass from sqlalchemy's built-in `Base` for declarative classes, and simply add these methods to my customclass. Whether or not the elixir functions will work as-is, I have not yet tested.

The functions both use:

```
mapper = sqlalchemy.orm.object_mapper(self)
```

and then use that mapper object to access everything. Is object_mapper still the recommended way to do this in SA-0.8 and later? Any caveats I should know about?